# algo problem - fewest choice that maximizes score

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The problem statement is as follows:

science tournament is taking place where each team can design solar vehicle with following scoring system:

- you can submit 0 < D < 20 different designs to compete
- each design will be given different score penalty (based on weight, dimension, production cost, material used, etc)
- for every design submitted, penalty score will be applied immediately and the total penalty score will serve as each team's starting score. more design you submit, the higher the penalty score will be
- each design will run all available terrains, once each
- each design will be given score 0 - 100 based on how many km it travels in an hour on different terrains. there will be 0 < T < 30 terrains
- we get only 1 score from each terrain. if there are multiple designs in the same terrain, the highest score will be awarded

| D # | penalty score | T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 7 |
| D2 | 2 | 8 | 8 | 12 |
| D3 | 3 | 15 | 16 | 8 |

if we submit all 3 designs, the total penalty score for our team is 6, making our initial score -6
and our terrain scores:

T1      -> D3 15 points

T2      -> D3 16 points

T3      -> D2 12 points

penalty ->    -6

-------------------------+

total   ->    37 points

D1, even if its penalty score is the lowest, is actually useless, and we dont need to submit it in the first place, thus, we can score 38 points if we only submitted D2 and D3. we need to find the highest score we can get given D designs and T terrains. we can pick and choose which design(s) we want to submit into the tournament.

brute force will give you Big O of D!
is there any better way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think brute force is `O(D)`, but rather `O(T*D*2^D)`. If you wanted to do better than brute force, you would have to implement a dynamic programming solution, and I am not sure off the top of my head what the time complexity would be, but most likely it would have `O(D*T)` memory complexity at least.

Comment: @WilliamFleetwood oh, could you elaborate more on the O(D*T) solution?

Comment: @WilliamFleetwood The DP solution will take exponential time and space.

Comment: Yeah, your right. I didn't really think too hard about it, that's why I couched my statement with  *at least* lol.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP hard.

To show that, let's reduce the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) to this one.

Let's assign one terrain per element, and one design per set.  Every design has a penalty of 1.  A design will perform 1 on a terrain that is not in its set, and will perform `2 * number_of_designs` on one that is.  It is straightforward to prove that the optimal tournament submission is the smallest set of designs corresponding to a set cover in the original design.  So if we can solve your problem efficiently, then we can find the minimal set cover.

I would suggest attempting some kind of [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm to solve this.  Either exactly or heuristically.